# Overload && for lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, types

I want to overload the operator `&&` for lambdas that takes as their input an arbitrary (single) value and yields a `bool`, i.e., something like:

```
auto operator&&( func_t lhs, func_t rhs )
{
  return []( auto x ){ return lhs(x) && rhs(x) };
}
```

However, I have no idea how I have to define `func_t` so that is corresponds to the type of the desired lambdas (i.e., a lambda that takes an arbitrary single input and yields a `bool`)

Has anyone an idea how this can be implemented?

Comment: You can't name the type of a lambda, and each one has a unique type. And you probably don't want to overload `&&`, since you will not get the expected short-circuiting behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a good idea because, as [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo) mentioned, **you won't get short-circuiting** and in my opinion the code will be misleading to the readers.

Anyway, `std::function` is a costly abstraction and should be avoided here, as you don't need its features.

Using a *template function* and [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) will work:

```
template <typename T>
using returns_bool_when_called_with_int = 
    std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T&>()(std::declval<int>())), bool>;

template <typename T0, typename T1>
using lambda_and_enabler = std::enable_if_t
<
    returns_bool_when_called_with_int<T0>{} && 
    returns_bool_when_called_with_int<T1>{}
>;

template <typename T0, typename T1, typename = lambda_and_enabler<T0, T1>>
auto operator&&( T0 lhs, T1 rhs ) 
{
    // Note that `lhs` and `rhs` are being captured by copy.
    // See the note at the end of the post for a more general alternative.
    return [=]( auto x ){ return lhs(x) && rhs(x); };
}
```

The code above can be used as follows:

```
int main()
{
    auto l0 = [](int x){ return x % 3 == 0; };
    auto l1 = [](int x){ return x % 2 == 0; };
    auto l_and = l0 && l1;

    assert(l_and(6));

    assert(!l_and(5));
    assert(!l_and(4));    
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/T0YJ1Jhhkz3lv3gq)

---

*Note:* you may want to [*perfect forward*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) your `lhs` and `rhs` lambdas into the lambda returned by `operator&&`, in order to avoid unnecessary copies and support *reference semantics*. I recently wrote an article about that: ["capturing perfectly-forwarded objects in lambdas"](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/capturing_perfectly_forwarded_objects_in_lambdas.html).

Your generic `operator&&` function would then look something like this:

```
template <typename T0, typename T1,
    typename = lambda_and_enabler<std::decay_t<T0>, std::decay_t<T1>>>
auto operator&&(T0&& lhs, T1&& rhs) 
{
    return [lhs = FWD_CAPTURE(lhs), rhs = FWD_CAPTURE(rhs)](auto&& x) mutable
    { 
        return access(lhs)(x) && access(rhs)(x); 
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the arguments of lambda are known, you can use cast to `std::function`, like this:

```
std::function<bool (int)> operator &&( std::function<bool (int)> lhs, std::function<bool (int)> rhs )
{
  return [&]( int x ){ return lhs(x) && rhs(x); };
}
```

Usage:

```
auto f = [](int x){ return false; } && [](int x){ return true; };
```